How to Configure Debian Server with ISP-Delegated Static IPs?
I'm setting up a Debian server to act as both a router and a server, but I've encountered issues with my ISP's unique static IP assignment method. Here's the situation:
I have been assigned two static IPs: 66.161.243.109 and 66.161.243.110 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.252. My goal is to assign 66.161.243.109 to the Debian server.
The Problem:
My ISP uses a method called subnet routing (or IP address delegation) instead of directly assigning static IPs to the router's WAN interface. The router dynamically receives an IP address that serves as the gateway for the static IP block. Static IPs are routed through this dynamic WAN IP rather than being assigned directly to the router.
This essentially means that:

The static IPs are configured on devices behind a router.
The WAN IP dynamically assigned to a router by the ISP is used as a gateway for the static IPs.

I understand this setup conceptually, but I am having trouble making it work in practice.
Current Configuration:
Here is my /etc/network/interfaces setup:
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
    pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables.rules

# Virtual interfaces for static IP addresses on eno1
auto eno1:1
iface eno1:1 inet static
    address 66.161.243.109
    netmask 255.255.255.252

# The 2nd network interface as DHCP router
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

What I've Tried:
To ensure outbound packets use the static IP address, I added this iptables rule:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -j SNAT --to-source 66.161.243.109

However, this caused:

100% packet loss when trying to ping external addresses.
curl ifconfig.me hangs indefinitely.

I've tried various configurations and workarounds, but I haven't been able to make it work.
Question:

How can I configure my Debian server to properly use 66.161.243.109 for outgoing traffic while keeping eno1 functional with the ISP's dynamically assigned IP?
Do I need to adjust routing, NAT, or iptables settings to make this work?
Alternatively, am I forced to use a dedicated router between the modem and my server to use the static IP addresses?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Does this setup work without the virtual interface and iptables rule?

@RobM yes, if I only remove the iptables rule then it works, but the dynamic IP address from DHCP (the ONT) is used as the public IP address instead of the desired static IP. Same thing without the virtual interface, it works through the dynamic IP.

Have you been able to use your static IPs in the intended way? I'm just trying to get my head around what's going wrong, because from the sounds of it your setup should work.

What happens if you just have the virtual interface but no iptables rule? If that works but connections default to the dynamic ip, try curl --bind 66.161.243.109 ifconfig.me or curl --bind eno1:1 ifconfig.me

@RobM yes, I had a ZyXEL ZyWALL 110 router that i used to route both of the static IPs to my other servers/devices. It was setup using virtual interface, SNAT and routing table, but the router itself used the dynamic IP address, if that makes sense. curl option --bind is unknown, but if i use curl --interface 66.161.243.109 ifconfig.me or curl --interface eno1:1 ifconfig.me then it does show the static IP as desired.

Oh right you are, 2 am moment. That's great, your setup does work, the trick is just going to be getting the little details right. Is it very important to you that everything you do appear to be coming from your static IP, or do you only have a few services where that's important?

My desired setup would be anything the server does would appear to be coming from the static IP, except for those connected through eno2 (isc-dhcp-server), they would use the dynamic IP. If not possible, then everything uses the static IP.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Can you verify with tcpdump -n -i eno1 to see 1) what packets are being sent when you run the curl command, 2) what packets are being received? I kind of suspect that the ISP hasn't correctly set up routing of the addresses at all, so it might be that your server is sending packets from the desired address but isn't receiving anything back...

Conceptually the method your ISP uses is even simpler than "directly assigning static IPs to the router's WAN interface" – it's what would've been done before NAT became so widespread... And, if they routed you a /30, it means you actually have four addresses, from .108 to .111, as the mechanism means you're not required to assign those addresses as a /30 subnet – you can assign them as individual /32's – and the "first&last reserved" rule does not apply when there is no subnet.

@grawity oh so i actually have 4 IP addresses i can use, that's awesome!

Yes, but they need to be configured on interfaces as /32, i.e. netmask 255.255.255.255 if you want to use the long syntax. (Which in your case makes more sense than configuring as /30 anyway, since it sounds like you're not really setting up a subnet to be broadcast on eth0, you're just using those as "floating" addresses on the same system, so /32's are a better fit.)

A /30 subnet doesn't give you 4 addresses because the first and last are reserved, .109 and .110 is correct

@RobM: Don't confuse subnets and routes. They have a /30 routed to them, they don't have a /30 subnet, so OP's server has the final say whether to make it a subnet or not. If they don't configure it as a subnet, then there are no broadcast addresses and therefore nothing is reserved.

Well I've learned something, thanks

It’s likely that a configuration change or setting adjustment during my initial attempts caused the issue. While troubleshooting, I observed some unexpected behavior and decided to perform a complete reinstall of Debian to ensure a clean starting point.
After starting over, I found that the following configuration was sufficient to make the server use the static IP address:

Virtual Interface Configuration in /etc/network/interfaces:
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp

auto eno1:1
iface eno1:1 inet static
    address 66.161.243.109
    netmask 255.255.255.252


iptables Rule:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -j SNAT --to-source 66.161.243.109



With these in place, the server successfully used the static IP address for outgoing traffic.
